# Perform actions before all WebTests in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, load-testing, stress-testing, webtest

I want to run some code (obtain a oauth valid token) before sending the SOAP requests of my webtests.
I am using Visual Studio.
I want to run the code that obtains the OAuth code before ALL test, not on each one.
¿Is that possible?
Thnaks!!

Comment: Has you question been answered? If not then please [edit] it to better explain what you want. If it has been answered then please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the web tests are being run as part of a load test then you can create a [load test plugin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243153(v=vs.110).aspx) and run some code from the [load test starting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.loadtesting.loadtest.loadteststarting(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

Your question reads as if you need to run one web test (possibly it contains just one request) to get the token and then run all the other tests. This can be achieved by using two scenarios in the load test. The first scenario contains the get-token web test, it is set to have one user and one iteration. The second scenario runs all the other web tests, the only change to it is to set its `Delay Start Time` property to a value that allows the get-token web test to complete.